# Accent sensitive FULL TEXT search (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, accent-sensitive

Hopefully I just can't see the forest for the trees but my full text search behaves very strangely and I cannot solve this by myself. (I tried to search for a solution but so far no luck, so any help is greatly appreciated.)

So my problem is: if I search for "**tök**" (it means "pumpkin" in Hungarian) the list also contains results with "**tok**" (which means "case"). If I search for a pumpkin I clearly don't want a phone case or such things.

My system is MySQL every table is in **InnoDB, utf8_general_ci**

this is the ( simplified ) query:

```
SELECT id_item,item_title,tag_name, MATCH (item_title) AGAINST ('tök' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS title_relevance, MATCH (tag_name) AGAINST ('tök' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS tag_relevance 
FROM item_translations 
WHERE NULL IS NULL 
AND (   MATCH (tile_item_title) AGAINST ('+tök' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ) OR MATCH (tag_name) AGAINST ('+tök' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ) ) 
AND id_language=1 
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, tag_relevance DESC 
LIMIT 0,40
```

PS: the keywords are not always in Hungarian because this website is multilingual  so I need a relatively flexible solution which works with most of the accented letters (if it's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality in a string comparison is specified by the collation. `general` will treat every letter like their (latin) base character. You need to specify a collation that supports the accents and umlauts that you want to be distinct.

The collation includes the language specifics. E.g. for spanish, `n < ñ < o` (while `n = ñ` for basically every other language), for swedish you have `Y = Ü`, for german (and most collations) there is `ß = ss`, and for hungarian (and many other collations) you have `o < ö`.

So for a hungarian site, you may want to choose `utf8_hungarian_ci`, and if your software is localizable to a specific language (and audience), you may want to adjust the collation of that column or let the administrator choose one. Unfortunately, for a fulltext search (in contrast to other string comparisons like `=` or `order by`), you cannot specify a collation in the query on the fly, so you need to choose a single one.

On a general multilanguage site, most users will probably expect a search to fit a very general english/russian/chinese-schema, and would not be surprised if they find `tök` when entering `tok`. They might even be irritated to not get those, especially if they do not have an `ö` on their keyboard and actually want to buy a pumpkin (and know the hungarian word for it). Most search engines will actually try to not be too narrow, and want to find `café` when you enter `cafe`, and oftentimes put some work into being able to find `café` when you enter `coffee`, `caffé` or `cafée`.

There is no language that will handle every accent and umlaut differently though. If you really want to distinguish every single special character, you may want to try `utf8_bin` (although I am not sure if I would call it *most flexible*). It is important to note that it is case sensitive, but since a fulltext search is always case insensitive, this would not matter. If you do other string comparisons on this column (e.g. `like`), this can be problematic though. Also, you will loose language specific behaviour, e.g. `Y = Ü` or `ß = ss` (unless you implement it yourself).

Comment: Thank you @Solarflare this was super helpful!